# How to pipe text into stdin

Tags: linux, unix, pipe, stdin

I want to do something like

`cat "username\npassword" | git push` so that git gets the username and password since it expects the first line of stdin as username and second line of stdin as password but it doesnt work.

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git specifically reads from the terminal, it does not just read from stdin (that's why you won't see your password displayed in the terminal). Most applications taht read a password will work like that.

You need to use one of Git's non-interacitve authentication methods.